# Intersection notation with multiple variables?

Tags: notation

I have a set with the notation $\mathbb{M}_{b}^{p}$ where $b,p$ define some kind of attribute of that set.

The union of the sets with all possible values for $b,p$ is easy:

$\bigcup_{b=0}^{\infty} \bigcup_{p=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{M}_{b}^{p}$

However, how do I notate the intersection?

I guess this is wrong:

$\bigcap_{b=0}^{\infty} \bigcap_{p=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{M}_{b}^{p}$

because it would first take the intersection with $p$ and then intersect the result with $b$.

This one is better:

$\bigcap_{b,p=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{M}_{b}^{p}$

But now I fear that it is unclear that I want all possible combinations of $(b,p)$ and not just $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, etc.

So, how do I notate the intersection correctly?

---

Update: Just an example of how $\mathbb{M}_{b}^{p}$ could be defined, in case the notation is confusing:

$\mathbb{M}_{0}^{0} := {6}$ ,
$\mathbb{M}_{0}^{1} := {7}$ ,
$\mathbb{M}_{1}^{0} := {7}$ ,
$\mathbb{M}_{1}^{1} := {8}$

Comment: $\bigcap_{b=0}^{\infty} \bigcap_{p=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{M}_{b}^{p}$ is not wrong

Comment: @MajaBlumenstein Does that mean that $\bigcap_{b=0}^{\infty} \bigcap_{p=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{M}_{b}^{p} \neq \bigcap_{b=0}^{\infty} (  \bigcap_{p=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{M}_{b}^{p} ) $   ?

Comment: $\bigcap_{b=0}^{\infty} (  \bigcap_{p=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{M}_{b}^{p} )=\bigcap_{p=0}^{\infty} (  \bigcap_{b=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{M}_{b}^{p} )$ and hence 
$\bigcap_{b=0}^{\infty} (  \bigcap_{p=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{M}_{b}^{p} )=\bigcap_{b=0}^{\infty} \bigcap_{p=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{M}_{b}^{p}$

Comment: Hm... I think I understand why I am confused.

The term $\bigcap_{b=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{M}_{b}^{p}$ cannot be solved, because we don't know $p$ . So it is not possible to do this intersection first, as the parentheses implies.

Neither can be  $\bigcap_{p=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{M}_{b}^{p}$ solved, since $b$ is not known.

Is that a problem?